# Depending on the Order of array values, how to map the JSON values appropiately?

Tags: jquery

I have a JSON in this format

```
var orderjson = 
    {
        "display": {
            "ServiceCharge": "1",
            "ServiceTax": "2",
            "order": [
                "ServiceCharge",
                "ServiceTax",
                "VAT",
                "DISCOUNT",
                "OTHERS"
            ],
            "VAT": "3",
            "OTHERS": "4",
            "DISCOUNT": "5"
        }
    }
```

I am extracting the order as shown below , but couldn't map them appropriately

This is my program

```
var orderOfDisplay = orderjson.display.order;

var ServiceCharge = orderjson.display.ServiceCharge;
var ServiceTax = orderjson.display.ServiceTax;
var VAT = orderjson.display.VAT;
var OTH1 = orderjson.display.OTH1;
var DISCOUNT = orderjson.display.DISCOUNT;

var htmldata =  '';

for(var i=0;i<orderOfDisplay.length;i++)
{
     htmldata+= '<tr><td align="right" valign="middle" width="50%">'+orderOfDisplay[i]+'</td> \
    <td align="right" valign="middle" width="50%">Rs. '+ServiceCharge+'</td> \
    </tr>';


}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2kbet2hL/1/

Could you please help me

My expected output

```
ServiceCharge   Rs. 1
ServiceTax  Rs. 2
VAT                   Rs. 3
DISCOUNT    Rs. 5
OTHERS                     Rs. 4
```

Comment: What does your expected output?

Comment: @Panoptik Thanks , i have edited my question the expected output .

Comment: One thing doesn't match: order-array has item `OTHERS` but display-object has property `OTH1` instead. Is it intended?

Comment: Sorry its  a mistake , both have the same name as OTHERS

Comment: Edited my question to avoid confusion .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change inside your `htmldata`:

```
ServiceCharge
```

to:

```
orderjson.display[orderOfDisplay[i]]
```

**EDIT** Then all the vars `ServiceCharge, ServiceTax, VAT, OTHERS, DISCOUNT` are not needed any more.

Comment: Thank you very much , i was trying the similar solution , but i was getting cannot read property of 0 .

Answer (score 0):

i hope this may be your expected result

```
for(var i=0;i<orderOfDisplay.length;i++)
{
     htmldata+= '<tr><td align="right" valign="middle" width="50%">'+orderOfDisplay[i]+'</td> ';
     if(orderOfDisplay[i]=="OTHERS"){
         orderOfDisplay[i]="OTH1";
     }
   htmldata+=' <td align="right" valign="middle" width="50%">Rs. '+orderjson.display[orderOfDisplay[i]]+'</td> \
    </tr>';


}
```